# insert and update at the same time with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have another problem again on querying in CodeIgniter,
I'll try to insert and update a "comment" on my website, but it's not working yet.

Here's my code :

on the Models (news_model.php)

```
public function simpan_komentar() {
 $data = array(
    'noid' => $_POST['noid'],
    'kategori' => $_POST['kategori'],
    'nama' => $_POST['nama'],
    'pekerjaan' => $_POST['pekerjaan'],
    'detail' => $_POST['detail'],
    'created_at' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s'),

    );
 $data1 = array(
   'komentar' => 'komentar + 1',
  );
 $this->db->insert('komentar',$data);
 $this->db->update('news',$data1);
 }
```

The insert query is working, but the update query didn't work
Can you tell me where's my fault?
Thanks

Comment: field komentar is int ?

Comment: yes, sir.. it's an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->set('komentar', 'komentar+1', FALSE);
//add your where condition if any
$this->db->update('news');
```

Comment: in your model. replace your `$this->db->update('news',$data1);` with my code.

Comment: Sorry sir, I forgot to call the function, it works.!! thank you sir